# Having some questions on pthread_create()

Tags: c, pthreads

guys. I am having some trouble dealing with the pthread_create in C:

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &helper, &i);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    printf("i is %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}

void *helper(void *arg) {
    int *num = (int *) arg;
    *num = 2;
}
```

when I compile it by using gcc, I get this kind of compile error:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'helper'
>           pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &helper, &i);

Could someone please tell me how to handle the last two arguments?

Comment: My advice: do not start with the threads, start with basic C coding. Not knowing that the function must be known (defined or declared) in code above where it is called is basic knowledge. Do not take it personally, please! Everybody started coded some time! :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time you use `helper` (as argument to `pthread_create()`), it's definition/declaration isn't available to the compiler.

Move the `helper()` function definition *above* main function or provide a protoype or declaration for `helper()`.

Also:

1) The cast in:

```
int *num = (int *) arg;
```

is unnecessary. It could simply be:  `int *num = arg;`.

2) The thread function `helper()` should return a pointer. Unless you intend to return any value, you could do:

```
return NULL;
```

at the end of it. This is required by Pthreads library.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with forward declaration. Put forward declaration before the main function.

```
void *helper(void *arg);
```

Or

define function above the main function.